# In Asp.Net 5 where does %DNX_PATH% in the wwwroot/web.config come from?

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-core

I'm trying to understand the boot process for and Asp.net 5 app running on IIS or IIS Express.  My understanding so far is that when a request comes in to IIS, it runs the httpPlatform handler due to the following code specified in the wwwroot/web.config file:

```xml
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
     <handlers>
         <add name="httpPlatformHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
     </handlers>
     <httpPlatform processPath="%DNX_PATH%" arguments="%DNX_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" startupTimeLimit="3600"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

So when IIS runs the httpPlatformHandler, I believe it gets it's config information from the httpPlatform tag above.  This is correct right?  Where does "%DNX_PATH% come from?  and Where does "%DNX_ARGS%" come from?  How do these place holders get their values?

If I can understand this, then I can probably get a better idea of what the next step in the process is.  Thanks!

Comment: Have you heard of environment variables? :) They [seem to be set](https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/commit/050fa03c223f2b442a2907a470a53b5b3c5b1974) in the `web.cmd`.

Comment: @CodeCaster Thanks, it would seem that way at first blush but see my response below to Maxime.  In this case I think the variable in web.cmd just happens to be named the same but that's not where it's getting set for the what is used in the web.config.  At least I don't see how it can be since the web.config is what's causing the web.cmd to get ran and it'd have to have a value before the web.cmd runs.

Answer (score 0):

`%DNX_PATH%` is set when you install ASP.NET 5.

When you download the installer from http://get.asp.net, it will automatically download the first piece of the puzzle which is `dnvm`.

dnvm will allow you to get the latest (and previous) .NET runtime.

This runtime will be used in `web.cmd` to create the variable `%DNX_PATH%` that will then be inserted in that configuration file.

It is important to know that you do need `dnx` installed on this machine to run it.

Comment: Maxime, it's true that there is a %DNX_PATH% variable set in the web.cmd file but "%DNX_PATH% in the web.config ultimately gets set in RC1 Update 1 to "..\approot\web.cmd", so infact this line in the web.config is what causes the httpPlatformHandler to run the web.cmd.  Therefore it can't be the web.cmd code that is setting the %DNX_PATH% that is in the web.config.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Yeah agreed. Deleting answer since it doesn't make sense. Not enough coffee I guess.